# Double click on Facebook share button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, onclick

I have a button to share web content on Facebook on a project and when I click it doesn't works. The button just works when the users make a  double click... :(

My code:

**Html:**

```
 <button>
    <img src = "images/socialButtons/56/facebook.png" id = "Item-A" onclick="shareFb(this.id)">
 </button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function shareOnFacebook(e, id){
e.preventDefault();
FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        name: '',
        link: 'http://anurl.com/'' + id + '.jpg',
        picture: 'http://anurl.com/'+ id +'.jpg',
        caption: '',
        description: "",
        message: ""

    }
);
}

function shareFb(id){

$('#'+ id +'').click(function(e){
    shareOnFacebook(e, id);
});

}
```

I have implemented the following script on my index.html (the button is on this file)

```
<!-- Facebook SDK JavaScript -->
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '#myFacebookAppIdNumber',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.5'
    });
};

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

I really appreciate any help ;)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: side note: there is no message parameter for the feed dialog

Answer (score 1):

It takes two clicks because you are attaching a click event after you click it. Why do that? Get rid of the inline click.

So add a common class:

```
<img class="share" id="foo" src="bar.gif" />
```

Attach the event to the class

```
$(".share").on("click", function (e) {
    shareOnFacebook(e, this.id);
});
```

The code above needs to run at the end of your document or on document ready. You can also use event delegation instead to add just one event handler.

```
$(document).on("click", ".share", function (e) {
    shareOnFacebook(e, this.id);
});
```

Comment: not sure why jquery for the simple task of attaching a click event, but he did it too, so...the answer is definitely correct :)

Comment: btw, you should add that FB.ui can only be opened on direct user interaction else it will be blocked in the browser.

Comment: lol...fixed typo ;) - people use jquery way too often, that´s really sad :(